# Importing function to different file, Reactjs + Material UI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I've declared a function, called search in separate file, and now I want to import it to main file, can someone suggest me the solution? All imports are already made, and no issues with this file, however in web page, the search is not working, if I move this code to main file, it working, what it could be?

```
export default function styledSearchBar({
     activeSearch,
     hideSearchAct,
     hideSearchBtn,
}){
     // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
     const classes = useStyles();
     return (
         <React.Fragment>
             <div 
                 ref       = { activeSearch } 
                 className = { classes.wrapperSearch }
                 onClick   = { (event) => hideSearchAct(event) }>

                 <div className = { classes.__search__ }>
                     <div className = { classes.searchIcon }> <SearchIcon /> </div>
                     <InputBase
                         placeholder = "Search"
                         inputProps  = {{ 'aria-label': 'search' }}
                         classes     = {{
                             root:  classes.inputRoot,
                             input: classes.inputInput 
                     }} />
                     <CloseIcon
                         className = 'close-search'
                         onClick   = {() => hideSearchBtn()}
                         style     = {{
                             position: 'absolute', 
                             right:    -40,
                             left:     'unset',
                             cursor:   'pointer'
                     }} />
                 </div>
             </div>  
         </React.Fragment>
     );
}
```

Here how I call this function inside my main file

```
   <Searcher
       ref     = { activeSearch }
       onClick = { (event) => hideSearchAct(event) }
        />
```

Comment: How are you importing `styledSearchBar` in you main file? Also, it's best practice to name your React components as pascal cased.

Comment: As usual `import Searcher from 'Location';`

Comment: I'm using normal `camelCase`

Comment: I did not know about Pascal Case, I liked it. Thank you